# composer update shows lots of packages as abandoned and you should use another package

Tags: magento2.2.6

```
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package oyejorge/less.php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package zendframework/zend-captcha is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-captcha instead.
Package zendframework/zend-code is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-code instead.
Package zendframework/zend-config is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-config instead.
Package zendframework/zend-console is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-console instead.
Package zendframework/zend-crypt is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-crypt instead.
Package zendframework/zend-di is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-di instead.
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-form is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-form instead.
Package zendframework/zend-http is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-http instead.
Package zendframework/zend-hydrator is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-hydrator instead.
Package zendframework/zend-json is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-json instead.
Package zendframework/zend-math is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-math instead.
Package zendframework/zend-mvc is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-mvc instead.
Package zendframework/zend-psr7bridge is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-psr7bridge instead.
Package zendframework/zend-servicemanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-servicemanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-stdlib is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-stdlib instead.
Package zendframework/zend-validator is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-validator instead.
Package zendframework/zend-i18n is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-i18n instead.
Package zendframework/zend-log is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-log instead.
Package zendframework/zend-modulemanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-modulemanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-serializer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-serializer instead.
Package zendframework/zend-escaper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-escaper instead.
Package zendframework/zend-uri is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-uri instead.
Package zendframework/zend-server is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-server instead.
Package zendframework/zend-soap is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-soap instead.
Package zendframework/zend-text is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-text instead.
Package zendframework/zend-loader is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-loader instead.
Package zendframework/zend-view is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-view instead.
Package zendframework/zend-db is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-db instead.
Package zendframework/zend-session is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-session instead.
Package zendframework/zend-diactoros is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-diactoros instead.
Package zendframework/zend-filter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-filter instead.
Package zendframework/zend-inputfilter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-inputfilter instead.
```

my question is can I modifiy composer.json to remove/update as per the suggestion or do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace) functionally of composer, which is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905069/8374833) answer on SO. **But** you should not update the packages yourself to avoid any negative side effects. Magento requires these packages and there is already an open [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26335) to update those dependencies, so better let Magento handle this issue.